# Interfacing an Sqlite database using a web interface

Tags: html, sqlite, alasql

I'm relatively new to web design and i am looking for the best way to interface with an sqlite database using a web interface to adjust values that are stored in the database. the existing sqlite database will be stored locally on the device that also hosts the web server where the page is served from. i have found a few methods online using indexedDB,AlaSQL  and Websql but do not understand how to use these for a local database and not one created in the browser.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need server side code (php, c#, node.js) to access a database positioned on that machine. On the client you can use for example Ajax to call that code. For security/performance reasons it is not a good idea to put your database and webserver on one device.

Comment: Pleaes add information about what programming languarge is avaiable on your device